# Recuperar valor en tiempo real en CKEditor con Genexus? GX17U3

Tags: variables, genexus, ckeditor

Tengo un formulario en un WebPanel (.NET, GX17U3) en donde tengo varios campos de texto (variables) y con el método `.ControlValueChanging()` recupero lo que el usuario va escribiendo, pero necesito hacer lo mismo **en una variable con CKEditor aplicado**, y una vez que la seteo como CKEditor no tengo más disponible el método `.ControlValueChanging()` para declarar el evento. Alguien sabe si es posible realizar esto?

Código de ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr con CK editor (así funciona mi variable de texto):

```
Event &CampoDescripcion.ControlValueChanging(&NuevoValor)
    CambiarValorNombreItem.Submit('','CMP',&Context.ComunidadId,&CustomFieldId,'',&IdiomaId,&CampoNombre,&CampoDescripcion)
Endevent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por el momento el control CKEditor no soporta esos eventos.
La gente de GeneXus tiene ese cambio pendiente para agregar soporte a los mismos.

Comment: Muchas gracias! buscare alguna alternativa mientras tanto. Saludos!